# Stop flex element grow over max-height:max-content

Tags: css, flexbox

I've made two sections with `height:0 flex-grow:1` and set them `max-height: max-content` so they won't grow to much and when they will contain lots of elements each section will take 50% of vertical space. Here is an example: https://jsfiddle.net/3wogy5q4/17/
The problem is that `max-height: max-content` is ignored on Chrome and Fireforx BUT only on some computers. Do you guys have any idea why some computers ignor `max-content` and how to replace it?
[image]

```css
.main-screen {
  height: 60vh;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.col {
  background-color: red;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.first {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 95%;
  overflow: auto;
  height: 0;
  flex-grow: 1;
  max-height: max-content;
}

.second {
  background-color: green;
  width: 95%;
  overflow: auto;
  height: 0;
  flex-grow: 1;
  max-height: max-content;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-screen">
  <div class="col">
    <div class="first">
      <div>First</div>
      <div>First</div>
      <div>First</div>
      <div>First</div>
      <div>First</div>
      <div>First</div>
      <div>First</div>
      <div>First</div>
    </div>
    <div class="second">
      <div>Second</div>
      <div>Second</div>
      <div>Second</div>
      <div>Second</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm not seeing the problem on my computer but it seems like you would want `max-height: min-content;` instead of `max-height: max-content` meaning the maximum should be the minimum amount of space they need.

Comment: `max-content === min-content === auto` for height.

Comment: @JacobP min-content also works fine, but doesn't resoleve the issue. "Luckily" this problem occures also on my computer and I run the newest Chrome 84.0.4147.105

Answer (score 0):

> Do you guys have any idea why some computers ignore `max-content` and how to replace it?

If you're talking about the computers, and not the browsers, then maybe those computers are running outdated browsers.

Check the browser versions. Update the browsers.

http://browsehappy.com/

Answer (score 0):

Remove `flex-grow` from `.first` and `.second` and change `max-height` to be `height` on `.first` and `.second`.

```
  height: 60vh;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.col {
  background-color: red;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.first {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 95%;
  overflow: auto;
  height: max-content;
}

.second {
  background-color: green;
  width: 95%;
  overflow: auto;
  height: max-content;
}
```

Comment: This solution doesn't keep the 50/50 vertical split between sections when there is lots of elements. If the first section has twice as many elements as the second one the first section takes 2/3 of vertical space while the second section 1/3.

Comment: @Lad in your picture above of how it should work, it doesn't keep it 50/50. The first one is bigger, so this matches that image of how it should work.